# Close All Piped Commands if one close

Tags: command-line, pipe

I'm running at least 3 commands (with progs) using pipes. For example

```
program1 bla bla | program2 blabla | program3 bla bla
```

Is possible to close all `programX` PIDS automatically if at least one exits/stops?

Comment: If you are the author of the programs, yes of course. If they are traditional unix ("filter") programs, they probably do this already. Most reading from stdin stop when they reach end of file, and the one before them in the pipe should close when they get a "broken pipe".

Comment: Ok i see, most of the times the first program does not close because it goes into infinite loop (it isnt my program). So i guess if i take the pid from the first program and make a kill -9 all the others will be closed.

Comment: Each program needs to do proper error checking when writing data to stdout. They will get an EPIPE error, if there is no reading process anymore. It sounds like the first program is just writing away, never checking for any error conditions/returns.